# Why do some people prefer SQLite over MySQL? I am a MSSQL user

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am curios why some prefer MYSQL over SQLITE, i am interested on  learning MYSQL

Comment: so i will go for MYSQL since seems to be more user efficient.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is an embedded library, it requires no server process, and everything it saves is contained within a single, portable file. MySQL is an RDBMS server that's a lot more work to set up, but is multi-user, more scalable, and far more featured.

For example, SQLite is used for mobile applications as well as "development" instances of code where it's only lightly loaded. It can be used at scale but generally isn't, its simple design has limitations.

If you're writing a mobile application and need a local database, SQLite is not a bad call. Spinning up a huge, cumbersome MySQL process to do the same thing on a mobile device is a bad plan.

Although they're both "SQL databases" and have a lot of functional overlap, they're engineered to solve some very different problems. In some trivial use cases it might be an arbitrary choice as to which is best, but in most cases it's pretty obvious which of the two you need.

Comment: I was trying to build a Bot locally using Python, this provably works better using SQLITE (While Learning)

Comment: SQLite is pretty simple to get started with, so that's probably not a bad call. As your needs evolve you can explore using MySQL or PostgreSQL. Be careful with capitalization, though. It's "MySQL" and "SQLite", not "MYSQL" and "SQLITE". Like a lot of programming languages, many of us are case sensitive.